# python - create table and insert data from csv

Tags: python, sql, csv

I have numerous different .csv files structured like so -

```
"Company", "column2", "column3"
"ABC Corp", "John Doe", "212,345"
"DBE Ltd", "Victor Smith", "234,345"
```

I understand how to write these CSV files to a table, however I want to actually write these to a new table but I may not know the columns so I need it to dynamically scan the .csv file to get the column names from the first row for the CREATE TABLE portion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3428633/650884

Comment: I was going to reply but then it clicked.  This link helped.  I need to essentially read the first row as a separate array and pass each part of the array as a column in the table create command.  I'm going to tinker with it now.