# Python read CSV file columns and write file name and column name in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have many CSV files, need to read all the files in loop and write file name and all the columns (header in row 1) in an output file.

**Example**

*Input csv file 1* (test1.csv)

```
Id, Name, Age, Location
1, A, 25, India
```

*Input csv file 2* (test2.csv)

```
Id, ProductName
1, ABC
```

*Outputfile*

```
test1.csv  Id
test1.csv  Name
test1.csv  Age
test1.csv  Location
test2.csv  Id
test2.csv  ProductName
```

Many thanks for your help.

Update:
This code works fine for this purpose:

```
import os
import csv

ofile = open('D:\Anuj\Personal\OutputFile/AHS_File_Columns_Info.csv', 'w')

directory = os.path.join('D:\Anuj\Personal\Python')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
            fullfilepath = directory + "/" + file
            with open(fullfilepath,'r') as f:
                output = file +','+ f.readline()
                ofile.write(output)
```

Comment: you should reformat your code.

Comment: This should give you the help you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428532/how-to-import-a-csv-file-using-python-with-headers-intact-where-first-column-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clean solution using `csv` module for reading *and* writing

- open output file and create a `csv.writer` instance on its handle
- open each input file and create a `csv.reader` instance on their handle
- get first row using `next` on the `csv.reader` iterator: gets titles as list (with a small post-processing to remove the spaces)
- write titles alongside the current filename in a loop

code:

```
import csv

files=["test1.csv","test2.csv"]
with open("output.tsv","w",newline='') as fw:
    cw = csv.writer(fw,delimiter="\t")  # output is tab delimited
    for filename in files:
        with open(filename,'r') as f:
            cr = csv.reader(f)
            # get title
            for column_name in (x.strip() for x in next(cr)):
                cw.writerow([filename,column_name])
```

There are several advantages using `csv` module, the most important being that quoting & multi-line fields/titles are managed properly.

Comment: Many thanks. I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'writer'

Comment: I think you called your module `csv.py`. Rename it.

Answer (score 0):

But I'm not sure I understand you correctly.

```
import csv
from typing import List
from typing import Tuple

TableType = List[List[str]]


def load_csv_table(file_name: str) -> Tuple[List[str], TableType]:
    with open(file_name) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        headers = next(csv_reader)
        data_table = list(csv_reader)
        return headers, data_table


def save_csv_table(file_name: str, headers: List[str], data_table: TableType):
    with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        for row in data_table:
            writer.writerow(row)


input_files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']
new_table = []
new_headers = []
for file_name in input_files:
    headers, data_table = load_csv_table(file_name)
    if not new_headers:
        new_headers = ['Source'] + headers
    new_table.extend(([file_name] + line for line in data_table))
save_csv_table('output.csv', new_headers, new_table)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This code works fine for me:  import os
import csv

ofile = open('D:\Anuj\Personal\OutputFile/AHS_File_Columns_Info.csv', 'w')

directory = os.path.join('D:\Anuj\Personal\Python')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
            fullfilepath = directory + "/" + file
            with open(fullfilepath,'r') as f:
                output = file +','+ f.readline()
                ofile.write(output)

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to use `readline()` on the file object:

```
files=["test1.csv","test2.csv"]
for my_file in files:
    with open(my_file,'r') as f:
        print my_file, f.readline()
```